# Is it ok to Install maven if I already have installed maven eclipse plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin

I have maven eclipse plugin and I want to use a jar file in my project that is not supported in maven so I found out I have to do something like this :

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=c:\kaptcha-2.3.jar -DgroupId=com.google.code 
-DartifactId=kaptcha -Dversion=2.3 -Dpackaging=jar
```

So I have to install maven to issue that command but won't that cause redundancy with maven plugin ?

Comment: It's fine to do so - I have m2eclipse and some software I installed also installed maven into my system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is no problem if you have both maven and eclipse maven plugin installed. I only use eclipse maven plugin for its pom.xml file editor. I do all other operations about maven through the command line.

Besides, the plugin (m2eclipse) I used, sometimes give strange dependency errors although everything is fine. Because when I run a "mvn install" for the project, it is built successfully. So, I think using maven itself is more reliable.

Answer (score 6):

You can install multiple different versions of maven, and configure m2eclipse to use a specific instance, see the setting under Window > Preferences > Maven > Installations.

Managing multiple different versions on the command line is controlled by the PATH environment variable, you would normally define an environment variable M2_HOME which specifies the home directory of the version that you are currently using, and then add $M2_HOME/bin or %M2_HOME%\bin to your path environment variable.