# Maven plugin install with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, plugins, maven

I am new to Maven, I have to install maven plugin in eclipse. I am facing some issues in the same, as the inputs I am getting different sites are not working.
I have also gone through existing posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7139385/is-it-ok-to-install-maven-if-i-already-have-installed-maven-eclipse-plugin), which talks about running the command like :

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=c:\kaptcha-2.3.jar -DgroupId=com.google.code 
-DartifactId=kaptcha -Dversion=2.3 -Dpackaging=jar
```

but where do I run this command ??

[This site](http://mevenide.codehaus.org/maven-eclipse-plugin-plugin/) talks about adding as parameter **maven.repo.remote** like :

```
maven -DartifactId=maven-eclipse-plugin-plugin -DgroupId=mevenide -Dversion=0.3.1 plugin:download
```

BUt where are these parameter set ??

Please can someone help me with pointing some good resource, which gives easy steps to install maven plugin in eclipse?

My eclipse version: indigo release, Java EE IDE.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- Start with Eclipse Indigo Java EE edition
- [m2e](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/) is the maven integration for Eclipse.  Install this plugin in the IDE.
- Import maven project if you have any or create a new one

`mvn install:install-file` is used to install maven artifacts in local repository, if it cannot be automatically downloaded and installed by maven.  This is not normally required, but if you have to do this, you can go to `Run as` -> `Run Configurations...` and create an appropriate `Maven Build` configuration.

[maveide](http://mevenide.codehaus.org/maven-eclipse-plugin-plugin/) is not maintained and not to be referred.

Comment: Could you please elaborate : m2e is the maven integration for Eclipse. Install this plugin in the IDE. (Note: I am not able to view the video at office)

Comment: @Swagatika. Eclipse plugins are used for additional functionality.  You can go Help -> Install New Software... -> Specify http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases in Work with...

Answer (score 28):

If you are running eclipse Indigo for Java EE you can install the missing m2e plugin this way:

`Help-> Install new software -> Work with: Indigo -> General Purpose Tools -> m2e`

See also: [Where is m2eclipse?](http://www.sonatype.com/people/2011/06/where-is-m2eclipse/)

Comment: Silver bullet. This is general efficient method.

Comment: Fastest way to install m2e plugin!

Answer (score 5):

In the Indigo release, Maven is already included by the eclipse plugin [m2e](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/). At the plugins website, you will find plenty of material. The steps are normally:

1. Install eclipse with m2e
2. Install separately a [current maven version](http://maven.apache.org/) (depending on what you need, Maven 2.2.x or Maven 3.0.x)
3. Configure your installed Maven inside Eclipse due to the documentation. Do that in the section `Window > Preferences > Maven > Installations`. If that is not visible in Eclipse, you first have to install m2e with the normal installation procedure: `Help > Install New Software > Work with: Indigo > Filter text: m2e > Collaboration > m2e`. Then next, next, next ...

Hope that helps.

Comment: If its installed already, do i have to enable it someway ? As i am not able to see the option Update All Maven Dependencies under project .

Comment: You should go to `Window > Preferences > Maven > Installations`, and declare there your installed Maven installation. Then the configuration of that Maven installation will be used. I will update my answer to reflect that later.

Comment: I m not getting "Maven" option under Preferences ? Does that mean I don't have maven plugin installed in my IDE ?

Comment: Yes, it does. So first install the plugin `m2e` by using the normal eclipse mechanism.

Comment: I am sorry but could you please tell how : install the plugin m2e by using normal eclipse mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

**Eclipse > Help > Eclipse Marketplace...**

Search for `m2e`

Install `Maven Integration for Eclipse (Juno and newer)`. [It works for Indigo also]

[image]