# Eclipse Indigo SR2 plugin issues

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-indigo

I have downloaded the latest Eclipse Indigo SR2 (Eclipse for Java EE developers). I have also included JBoss Tools 3.3. for Eclipse Indigo SR2, and restared Eclipse. My problem is that I cannot see anywhere where to add JBoss 7 Runtime Server.

How do I make Eclipse reinstall its downloaded plugins?
Also, I am aware that m2e is now included in `Eclipse for Java IDE developers`. I went to Eclipse Marketplace and downloaded Maven. I cannot see it anywhere on Preferences.

How do I resolve these issues?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7385632/367285) helps you with your maven problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured this out, so let me share my solution that works (in Windows):

First, make sure that your Eclipse 3.7.2 (Indigo, SR2), runs with the Java 6 Virtual Machine. This can be achieved by configuring the `eclipse.ini` file and adding the `-vm` argument, as follows:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.100.v20110502
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
512M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
512m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vm
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_25/bin/javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms256m
-Xmx2048m
```

(**Never put the full path of javaw.exe in quotes**). Now, start Eclipse and install your updates.

Without adding the `-vm` argument, Eclipse will use the `%SYSTEMROOOT%\system32\javaw.exe` to run Eclipse. Even when the plugins are installed, they don't get added to the `features` and `plugins` directory.

This also resolved the issue of installing `Maven` in Eclipse.