# Maven not adding jars to classpath

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-3, m2eclipse

I'm using eclipse indigo and maven 3.1

When I add a new dependency in pom.xml and run maven clean by right-clicking on pom.xml, maven is downloading missing jars to my local repository but not adding them to my list of referenced libraries.

After many hours of struggling I found out that I can solve this by running

`mvn eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=2.0`

from command line each time after adding a new dependency. When I run maven clean from eclipse after doing this then the jars are added to referenced libraries.

Anybody know why this is happening like this?

Comment: because maven has no control over eclipse build path

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Be carefull not to mix up the [maven-eclipse-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/) and the [m2e](http://eclipse.org/m2e/) Maven eclipse integration.

You should use the Maven eclipse integration (m2). If you have maven commands in your IDE I suppose that you have installed m2e successfully (if not check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7385632/367285) answer). In this case you can convert the project to a Maven project and the Maven Dependencies will be added as a Library to your Build Path.

As far as I know, if you use `eclipse:eclipse` the *maven-eclipse-plugin* will "mess up" your eclipse *.classpath* file and put every dependency as an own entry to the buildpath (and possibly the m2e configuration will be overwritten).

So both "tools" have different concepts that must not be used together. You have to take a decision which integration you prefer - IMHO m2e is mostly used.

Comment: `eclipse:eclipse` can be described as a push-mechanism. With every change to the `pom.xml` you might need to close Eclipse, run the goal and start Eclipse again. Whereas the m2eclipse uses pulling. It 'listens' to every change of the pom.xml and can change the eclipse environment immediately (of force it with Update project from the context menu)